# DataBinding is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datagridview

I am using Windows application c#. When I bind the data table to  Datagridview it gets slow and I am getting a SQL connection timeout error.

At the same time my data table has bulk records.  How can I solve this problem?

Code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   con.StatisticsEnabled = true;
   con.Open();

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Stktrn_table", con);
   SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);           
   adp.Fill(dt);

   GridDisplay.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
 }

 SqlCommand cmdVoid = new SqlCommand("select party_no, smas_rtno,convert(numeric(18,2),SUM(smas_NetAmount)) as Amount from salmas_table where ctr_no=@tCounter and Smas_Cancel<>1 and smas_rtno<>0 and Smas_billdate=@tDate group by smas_rtno, party_no", con); 
cmdVoid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tDate", dpBillDate.SelectedDate.Value);
cmdVoid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tCounter", tCounterNoNew); 
SqlDataAdapter adpVoid = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdVoid); 
adpVoid.Fill(dtVoid);
```

Comment: try to optimize your query dont select *, Select those values which you need.

Comment: Use options like `LIMIT` to limit the number of datasets returned

Comment: I am using only select particular date wise....but i getting very slow... the above code was just a sample

Comment: may be then you need to add indexes on your table to improve the querying performance

Comment: There is nothing related to DataBinding in this question. If filling your data table from the database is slow, it will be slow regardless of if you are using WPF, WF, console etc. Data binding happens after the data table is populated in memory, so you cannot get sql errors during the binding phase.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Stktrn_table", con);
```

Will be your problem.  Do not select all rows from the database, limit it using [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

```
SELECT TOP 100 Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Stktrn_table
```

in general `SELECT *` is bad practice.

Or alternatively, implement paging so the rows are loaded on demand rather than upfront.

How does the query run within SQL Server management studio?  This should be your initial indicator of how long the query will return from the database.

You could also use a stored procedure which may give you a performance benefit over a raw SQL query.

Comment: Spot On!! @DarrenDavis

Comment: query wise i don't have any problem... i am using select particular date wise only... the above code was just a sample query. i am using stored procedure, indexing ..

Comment: @Munies - how rows are returned? The databinding should not be slow. Please paste relevant code so we can provide more accurate answers.

Comment: SqlCommand cmdVoid = new SqlCommand("select party_no, smas_rtno,convert(numeric(18,2),SUM(smas_NetAmount)) as Amount from salmas_table where ctr_no=@tCounter and Smas_Cancel<>1 and smas_rtno<>0 and Smas_billdate=@tDate group by smas_rtno, party_no", con);
                cmdVoid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tDate", dpBillDate.SelectedDate.Value);
                cmdVoid.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tCounter", tCounterNoNew);
                SqlDataAdapter adpVoid = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdVoid);
                adpVoid.Fill(dtVoid);

Answer (score 0):

First thing You should not use like this `Select * from table_name` instead this you should use select `column_1,column_2,column3,column_n` i.e. select only columns which you needed.

Second thing always use classes(BLL and DLL) instead of coding directly for database at page load or any form.

Third always use try catch block.

Third thing whenever you create a object, you should dispose that in finally block of try catch.
for ex.

```
DataTable dt = null;

SqlDataAdapter da = null;

SqlConnection con = null;
try

{

con=new SqlConnection("Connection_Source");

con.Open();

da = new DataAdapter("select * from table_name",con);

dt=new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

dataGridViewObj.DataSource=dt;

}

catch(Exception ex)

{

MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

}

finally

{

if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)

con.Close();

dt.Dispose();

if(dt!=null)

dt=null;

da.Dispose();
if(da!=null) da=null;
}
```

Comment: `Using` keyword do the same things without `Try .. Catch`.